# Reading all files in a package and copying the contents to a List or a map

Tags: java, directory, java.util.scanner, readfile

I am currently working on a machine learning project. I have a package/directory of java files and i want to read their contents. Later, i will apply other methods to achieve results.

The problem is that the given code reads the txt files, however, when i pass the directory containing java files it doesn't work properly. Following is what I did

1. I read the names of all files in a directory.
2. As every directory has different number of files and different structure of files and folders inside it. I am looking for a generic solution.
3. Next, I read the contents of every file and put it in a list or MAP or whatever

The given code is as follows. I have written 3 methods.

This method list all files in a directory and make a set

```
 // it will list all files in a directory.
    public Collection<File> listFileTree(File dir) {
      Set<File> fileTree = new HashSet<File>();
         for (File entry : dir.listFiles()) {
             if (entry.isFile())
                 fileTree.add(entry);
             else
                 fileTree.addAll(listFileTree(entry));
         }
         return fileTree;
     }
```

Here using the above method i have tried to read the contents of each file.

```
File file = new File("C:\\txt_sentoken");// c\\japa..if i use it code only show directory files
        Iterator<File> i = Util.listFileTree(file).iterator();
String temp = null;
        while(i.hasNext()){
            temp = Util.readFile(i.next().getAbsolutePath().toString());
            System.out.println(temp);           
        }
}
```

This is the readFile method

```
// using scanner class for reading file contents
public String readFile(String pathname) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(pathname);
    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int)file.length());
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    try {
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {        
            fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() + lineSeparator);
        }
        return fileContents.toString();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

If i pass a directory (in `File file = new File("C:\\txt_sentoken");`) containing txt files this code works but for java or c++ or other code directories or packages it doesn't.

Can anyone guide me in refining this code? Also if there is any API or generic solution available please share.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Java NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) to achieve your goal.

If you need any filtering you can put checks in the `FileVisitor`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
      System.out.println(readAllFiles("")); // <----- Fill in path
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static Map<Path, List<String>> readAllFiles(String path) throws IOException {
    final Map<Path, List<String>> readFiles = new TreeMap<>();
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(path), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
      @Override
      public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(file);
        readFiles.put(file, Files.readAllLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }
    });
    return readFiles;
  }
}
```

A Java 8 - also sorted - solution would be:

```
public static Map<Path, List<String>> readAllFiles(String path) throws IOException {
    return Files.walk(Paths.get(path)).filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p)).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(k);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } , (u, v) -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u));
    } , TreeMap::new));
}
```

Comment: I have tried to run it but getting some errors with BasicFileAttributes and SimpleFileVisitor. Can you show me a complete example?

Comment: @Skipper07 here you go. Tested with compliance level 1.7

Comment: I got `'java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1` exception while running it. Once i changed the `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` to `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` it worked. Don't know why.

Comment: @Skipper07 you got that exception because of the encoding of the files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I am thinking how to process this data for other requirements.

Comment: how can I only get the files of type *.txt using the code above? any suggestions?